Action of Symmetry Operators on Hamiltonian
I have been reading about Symmetry operators being applied to Hamiltonian and have attached the section from the paper I was reading from.

For Hermitian Systems
$$\mathcal{CHC^{-1}=-H}$$ Where $\mathcal{C}$ is a unitary operator

Here as shown $\mathcal{C}$ is a unitary operator which is equal to $\mathcal{UK}$ where $\mathcal{U}$ is a unitary operator and $\mathcal{K}$ is a conjugation operator. So similarly $\mathcal{C^{-1}}=\mathcal{KU^\dagger}$
When I try to solve above given LHS of $\mathcal{CHC^{-1}}$ I get the following result
$$
\mathcal{C H C^{-1}=U K H K U^{\dagger}=U H^* K U^{\dagger}}
$$
Here at second step I have just applied operator $\mathcal{K}$ over hamiltonian which gives $\mathcal{H}^*$ but how do I resolve $\mathcal{UH^*KU^\dagger}$?

Write out the full chain of arguments undergirding your conclusions. You hardly make any sense here.

Please do not post screenshots of textbooks.

There is a typo in your equations that was not present in the book print that you posted. The correct expression is
$$
\mathcal{CH^*C^{-1}=-H}.
$$
The presence of conjugation in l.f.s. is important, because as it is defined, $\mathcal C$ is not an unitary operator, but anti-unitary one (conjugation is anti-unitary and the product of an unitary and an anti-unitary operators results in an anti-unitary one). As it is, since $\mathcal K^2 = \mathbb I$, you'll get
$$
\mathcal{UH}\mathcal U^\dagger = \mathcal H.
$$
Without additional information about $\mathcal U$ and $\mathcal H$, nothing more could be said.

if you say that conjugation is anti unitary then wouldn't $K^2$=-I?

If you conjugate twice, you recover the initial vector
